# Should this still be in-play in Australian Rules Football?

Tags: rules, australian-rules-football

[image: Example of ball hitting the goal post]

We see in some AFL (Australian Football League) games that when a player kicks the ball at the goal, the ball can hit the post, then the ball bounces back onto the playing field.

**Should this still be in-play and the game continues**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rules 1.5 Scoring](http://www.footy.com.au/dags/FAQ1v1-5.html) [(2)](https://usafl.com/intro) helps in understanding this situation.

> 1.5.3 **If the ball hits the goal post, a behind is scored**. This is regardless of where the ball goes after hitting the goal post, e.g., back into the field of play, through the goals or whatever. Play stops as soon as the ball hits the goal post, and is restarted by a kick-in.

(my emphasis)

And

> 1.6.5 (a) After a behind has scored. Any player of the defending team kicks the ball from within the kick-off 'square' in front of goal, but only after the goal umpire has finished waving his flags. The player must *kick* the ball out to restart play.

Comment: But if the ball bounces off the post and back into the playing field, that should be play-on though shouldn't it?

Comment: @natural It doesn't matter  if the ball bounces off the post and back into the playing field or not, as indicated play stops and is restarted by kick-in.

Comment: What's hard about this rule? It hits the post, therefore a behind is scored and play stops. It should not be play on at all. This isn't football or hockey, it's AFL.